# .resx files not working with localisation

Tags: asp.net, localization, resx

Here's a snippet:

```
<ext:MenuItem runat="server" ID="miMenuDetails" Text="Show details" Icon="ApplicationForm" meta:resourcekey="miMenuDetails">
```

I'm trying to localise it using .resx files, but it doesn't work. The text is always 'Show details'. Here are the facts:

- the local resources folder contains Page.aspx.resx, Page.aspx.en.resx, and Page.aspx.de.resx files
- it also contains similar files for other pages
- each file has the same resource names (with different values)
- web.config contains the `<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />` line

What could be wrong? What am I missing? The above are also true for a different (smaller) page that works. Can it be something in the page code?

EDIT: I also tried this:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="en" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
```

but the page still uses default phrases.

Answer (score 0):

You also need the enableClientBasedCulture="”true”".
Look in here for more info about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.globalizationsection.enableclientbasedculture.aspx

In addition, wouldn't it be better to let the user determine the language using a drop down or two buttons?

Look at this article for more info on Globalization & Localization:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15313/Globalization-and-localization-demystified-in-ASP

Comment: The user is able to select a language himself, but when he's not done it yet, I want to use the browser language.

Comment: When the user chooses a language for himself, it'll be done via code. When it's the default language, it's done automatically, I just add the .resx files.

Comment: Not unless I want to lose my job. I can post a relevant part. What do you need?

Comment: :)
Just post the code that changes the thread's culture, the page directive of the specific page & the web.config (specially the globalization section).